# EPub viewer for Flex

Tags: apache-flex, epub

Does any such control exist out of the box for Flex?

I see people say things like "EPUB is just a zip file of XML and HTML files, so it shouldn't be too hard"... yeah, I get that... but if such a control exists, I wouldn't have to write it.

Has anyone seen anything like this?
Brian

Comment: As far as i know, no component exists. But, If you're able to easily build an HTML Viewer in ActionScript; then we should talk off-line.  We could turn it into a Flextras component and become overnight millionaires.

Comment: Right.  No HTML viewer in the browser.  But there is the HTML component in Air, and you can do some hacky things to put an IFrame on top of your app but I've never tried it. (http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/)  So it can probably be done.    Not something I want to write if I don't have to.

Comment: Yep, it sounds like HTML Component for AIR o the iFrame trick would be valid options.  Not the same as a native Flex viewer, but probably good enough.

Comment: Still have to deal with unpacking the HTML and images from the EPub file and serve them up to the browser... easier in Air, it seems.  Mostly sounds like a pain.

Comment: Brian sorry to say I don't think this exists.  If you didn't know about it already here's a as3zip reader package http://nochump.com/blog/archives/15 so you can read the files out of the ePub at least, from the looks of the files getting it to apply the css would likely be the worst part of making it work in terms of just displaying the chapters and text you can definitely pull it off easily, but to get the formatting correct will take either a hack as you describe or some serious work.

Comment: Compile CSS -> swf on a server with Java for loading at run-time into Flex http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/2008/01/compiler_api.html load the result from the Java request http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f8c.html apply it along with the contents of the chapter XHTML files into some extension of RichEditableText or something along those lines http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB, sorry I know this isn't an answer which is why it's posted as a comment but hope it helps if you do decide to go through with building it.

Comment: @shaunhusain: Why would applying the CSS be so hard?  It is referenced from the XHTML documents.  The HTML or flex-iframe component should take care of that for me.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Brian Genisio: If you were to load it dynamically via the Iframe method using the browser to interpret all the HTML and CSS this shouldn't be all that difficult.  The only problem is Flex doesn't let you load StyleSheets dynamically so far as I know you have to compile the css to a swf to apply a whole file, or else I suppose you could write something to parse the css and apply the style declarations individually to components.  If I'm wrong here please correct me and sorry for the misinformation but that's my understanding.

Comment: @Brian Genisio: I was assuming you're trying to pull this off as a self contained control within AS3 as opposed to using an IFrame overlay (I believe this suffers some performance issues due to the window mode of the plugin and getting it to integrate with other Flash content wouldn't be as easy, for example AS3 you could take advantage of views like this http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/3d-page-curl-effect-using-papervision3d/.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the walflower project, it needs updating to the new TLF though.

http://designwithoutdesign.blogspot.com/2010/07/working-with-epub-files-in-flash-and.html

http://wir35.com/teaser/

https://github.com/maxl0rd/walflower/